# Why `a` can be printed from `baz`?

Tags: javascript, this

```
const Foo = function(a){

  // bar doesn't belong to any instance
  function bar(){
    console.log(a);
  };

  this.baz = function(){
    console.log(a);
  }
}

const f = new Foo(7);
f.baz() // print 7
```

Hi stackoverflows, can someone explain to me why `f.baz()` can print the `a` ??  Having difficulty explaining this to someone else right now

Comment: Well, it’s in scope. Why wouldn’t this work?

Comment: What does `bar()` have to do with this? Why is it in the snippet?

Comment: @SebastianSimon
I still don't understand why it is in scope ?? can you tell me more on this

Comment: @EdwardSun It’s in scope because it’s inside a function that has the parameter `a`. That’s how scope works in JS. It’s lexical scope. See the third linked Q&A.